# Multiple MySQL Queries on One PHP Page

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following PHP/MySQL code:

```
function executeMultirowQuery($query) {
   $result = mysql_query($query);
   $table = array(); 

   if ($result == false) {
      $error = mysql_error();
      echo $error;
   } else {
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         $table[] = $row;
      }
      mysql_free_result($result);
   }

   return $table;
}
```

It basically executes the given query, and returns the result as a multi-dimensional array.
The second call  (and all subsequent calls) to this function result in a "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" error from MySQL.

Since I'm calling mysql_free_result() before I return I don't think its that I still have a request out there, but I can't think of any other reason it might be failing.

Any ideas?

*EDIT:*
If it makes any difference, I'm using this function to call stored procedures like this:

```
function getGroups($groupTypeID) {
   echo "getGroups";
   $query = sprintf("CALL getGroups('%s');", mysql_real_escape_string($groupTypeID));

   return $this->executeMultirowQuery($query);
}
```

This is typical of the way the executeMultirowQuery() function is used.

*EDIT:*
Here is my connection code:

```
$this->link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
$success = mysql_select_db($database);

if (!$this->link) {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Also, here is a sample query from the stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`blah`@`blah` PROCEDURE `getGroups`(
    IN inGroupTypeID INT )
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM `db`.`Groups`
   WHERE GroupTypeID = inGroupTypeID;
END
```

Again, this is typical of how the function is being used. None of the stored procedures returns multiple results sets (which I understand doesn't work in PHP/MySQL).

Comment: well...you do not call it before you return, read your code again. the line before the return is `}` and not the free result call.Any way, why do you try to invent the wheel, are you in learning phase?

Comment: The code looks alright to me; free_result is only called if there is a valid mysql result. I suspect the issue is with the sql queries that are beign run rather than the php code. Maybe...

Comment: @Itay I'm just learning my way around PHP/MySQL. I'm not using fancy tools like Zend Framework, etc., because they would be overkill for the kinds of things that I'm doing.

Comment: @Graham - once you have a good grasp of php+mysql it will get you much much faster to where you want to get using tools/FW. But, I think it is wise in the beginning to experiment with the raw code.

Comment: one more thing, show us how you connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stored procedure returns two resultsets - your data plus a count of the number of rows fetched so you need to call

```
next_result()
```

after each db call.

You'd also be better off using mysqli vs mysql (only the latest mysql extension supports sproc calls) then you can use the faster fetch_all method to populate your array.

```
$table = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It worked great, except for the fetch_all() call, which hung. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do a mysql_free_result() even when `$result == false`. Thus, move `mysql_free_result($result)` outside the else{} and just before the return.

The following links might help:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html

http://mike-hostetler.com/blog/2007/04/php-5-and-mysql-5-stored-procedures-error-and-solution-qcodo